# Parquet File re-write has slightly larger size in both Pandas / PyArrow

Tags: python, pandas, io, parquet, pyarrow

So I am trying to read a parquet file into memory, choose chunks of the file and upload it to AWS S3 Bucket. I want to write sanity tests to check if a file was uploaded correctly through either size check or `MD5` hash check between the local and cloud file on the bucket.

One thing I noticed is that reading a file into memory, either as `bytes` or `pd.DataFrame` / `Table`, and then re-writing the same object into a new file would change the file size, in my case increasing it compared to the original. Here's some sample code:

```ipython
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_parquet("data/example.parquet")
```

Then I simply write:

```ipython
from io import ByteIO
buffer = ByteIO()
df.to_parquet(buffer) # this can be done straight without BytesIO. I use it for clarity.
with open('copy.parquet', 'rb') as f:
    f.write(buffer.getvalue())
```

Now using `ls -l` on both files give me different sizes:

```bash
37089 Oct 28 16:57 data/example.parquet
37108 Dec  7 14:17 copy.parquet
```

Interestingly enough, I tried using a tool such as `xxd` paired with `diff`, and to my surprise the binary difference was scattered all across the file, so I think it's safe to assume that this is not just limited to a metadata difference. Reloading both files into memory using pandas gives me the same table. It might also be worth mentioning that the parquet file contains both `Nan` and `Nat` values. Unfortunately I cannot share the file but see if I can replicate the behavior with a small sample.
I also tried using `Pyarrow`'s file reading functionality which resulted in the same file size:

```python
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
with open('data/example.parquet', 'rb') as f:
    buffer = pa.BufferReader(obj)
table = pq.read_table(buffer)
pq.write_table(table, 'copy.parquet')
```

I have also tried turning on the `compression='snappy'` in both versions, but it did not change the output.

Is there some configuration I'm missing when writing back to disk?

Comment: Parquet always uses compression, and the result can therefore depend on your system, the compression engine, version, and settings, and the version of your parquet library. Generally I’d treat them as not terribly reproducible across environments as far as file hashes go. If you’re using a single docker env to write the files they should match.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I suspected it could be part of compression across systems especially with regards to null values. Unfortunately the files were produced as part of another library for which I have no information the environment it was hosted on. Then I guess I have to resort to manual DataFrame `compare` or `merge` functionality for checking equality.

Comment: yeah unfortunately I think that's the case. the pandas testing utilities such as [`pd.testing.assert_frame_equal`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html) might come in handy here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas uses pyarrow to read/write parquet so it is unsurprising that the results are the same. I am not sure what clarity using buffers gives compared to saving the files directly so I have left it out in the code below.

What was used to write the example file? If it was not pandas but e.g. pyarrow directly that would show up as mostly meta data difference as pandas adds its own schema in addition to the normal arrow meta data.

Though you say this is not the case here so the likely reason is that this file was written by another system with a different version of pyarrow, as Michael Delgado mentioned in the comments snappy compression is turned on by default. [Snappy is not deterministic between systems](https://groups.google.com/g/snappy-compression/c/W8v_ydnEPuc):

> not across library versions (and possibly not
> even across architectures)

This explains why you see the difference all over the file. You can try the code below to see that on the same machine the md5 is the same between files but the pandas version is larger due to the added meta data.

Currently the arrow s3 writer does not check for integrity but the S3 API has such a functionality. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/14888) to make this accessible via arrow.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import numpy as np
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

arr = pa.array(np.arange(100))
table = pa.Table.from_arrays([arr], names=["col1"])

pq.write_table(table, "original.parquet")

pd_copy = pd.read_parquet("original.parquet")
copy = pq.read_table("original.parquet")

pq.write_table(copy, "copy.parquet")
pd_copy.to_parquet("pd_copy.parquet")

$ md5sum original.parquet copy.parquet pd_copy.parquet                                                                                 
fb70a5b1ca65923fec01a54f85f17260  original.parquet
fb70a5b1ca65923fec01a54f85f17260  copy.parquet
dcb93cb89426a948e885befdbee204ff  pd_copy.parquet

1092 copy.parquet
1092 original.parquet
2174 pd_copy.parquet
```